# Using Multithreading or Multiprocessing to improve computational speed

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, optimization, multiprocessing

I am iterating through very large file size `[mesh]`. Since the iteration is independent, I would like to split my mesh into smaller sizes and run them all at the same time in order to lower computation time. Below is a sample code. For example, if `mesh` is of `length=50000`, I would like to divide the mesh into 100 and run fun for each mesh/100 at the same time.

```
import numpy as np
def fnc(data, mesh):
    d = []              
    for i, dummy_val in enumerate(mesh):
        d.append(np.sqrt((data[:, 0]-mesh[i, 0])**2.0 + (data[:, 1]-mesh[i, 1])**2.0))
    return d

interpolate = fnc(mydata, mymesh)
```

I would like to know to achieve this using multiprocessing or multithreading as I'm unable to reconcile it with the execution of my loop.

Comment: Looks like you can use broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the general idea. I couldn't test this since I do not have your data. The default constructor for `ProcessPoolExecutor` will use the number of processors on your computer. But since that determines the level of multiprocessing you can have, it will probably be more efficient to set the `N_CHUNKS` parameter to the number of simultaneous processes you can support. That is, if you have a processing pool size of 6, then it is better to just divide your array into 6 large chunks and have 6 processes do the work rather than breaking it up into smaller pieces where processes will have to wait to run. So you should probably specify a specific `max_workers` number to the `ProcessPoolExecutor` not greater than the number of processors you have and set N_CHUNKS to the same value.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
import numpy as np

def fnc(data, mesh):
    d = []
    for i, dummy_val in enumerate(mesh):
        d.append(np.sqrt((data[:, 0]-mesh[i, 0])**2.0 + (data[:, 1]-mesh[i, 1])**2.0))
    return d

def main(data, mesh):
    #N_CHUNKS = 100
    N_CHUNKS = 6 # assuming you have 6 processors; see max_workers parameter
    n = len(mesh)
    assert n != 0
    if n <= N_CHUNKS:
        N_CHUNKS = 1
        chunk_size = n
        last_chunk_size = n
    else:
        chunk_size = n // N_CHUNKS
        last_chunk_size = n - chunk_size * (N_CHUNKS - 1)
    with ProcessPoolExcutor(max_workers=N_CHUNKS) as executor: # assuming you have 6 processors
        the_futures = {}
        start = 0
        for i in range(N_CHUNKS - 1):
            future = executor.submit(fnc, data, mesh[start:start+chunk_size]) # pass slice
            the_futures[future] = (start, start+chunk_size) # map future to request parameters
            start += chunk_size
        if last_chunk_size:
            future = executor.submit(fnc, data, mesh[start:n]) # pass slice
            the_futures[future] = (start, start+n)
    for future in as_completed(the_futures):
        (start, end) = the_futures[future] # the original range
        d = future.result() # do something with the results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # the call to main must be done in a block governed by if __name__ == '__main__' or you will get into a recursive
    # loop where each subprocess calls main again
    main(data, mesh)
```